# you cook well; you cook good

Tags: adverbs, adjectives

(1) You cook **well**. 
(2) You cook **good**.

When an adverb follows after a verb as in (1), it sounds, I guess, smoother than (2). Yet (2) would not be not proper for there are predicative adjuncts in English. Do you use (2) expression actually? If you do, ‘*good*’ might show the subject’s property in the activity of the verb, I guess; so this is the difference from (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 2 = **NEVER**!*

"Good" is an adjective, "well" is a verb. We are describing a verb so we must use an adverb, hence option 1 is the only possible option.

This comes from a British English perspective since I know there are differences between this and American English.

Comment: I can see there is this example in British National Corpus: "You can cook _good_."

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=You+can+cook+good&mysubmit=Go)?

Comment: Also, take care with searching for this short phrase. I say this because "I cook good food" is a legitimate phrase (good = adjective describing food).

Comment: Yes, I saw the example: "You can cook good, you can look good." So both good's would take the same function as predicative adjectives?

Comment: I suppose so, but this is a contrived expression where the first good is not correct, but is used to make the phrase sound better. For example, consider the difference in meaning between "it looks good" and "it looks well".

Comment: @Listenever *Good* instead of *well*, with adverbial sense, is very common in the vernacular - "Peralta hits pretty good for a shortstop". But as JMB says, this is not tolerated in even informal writing, except in dialogue or self-consciously  'folksy' expressions like the one you cite.

Comment: I think you mean "well" is an adverb?